# How can I add a class, id or attribute to a twig include?

Tags: html, twig, octobercms, craftcms

I am working on a project that uses twig.
Each page uses

```
{% extends "_layouts/_master" %}
```

Inside the _layouts/master there is a body tag

```
<body class="{% block bodyClass %}{% endblock %}">
```

Can I add a class to the body tag from a page that is using the include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override parent block (defined in `_layouts/_master`) in child template (the one that extends parent). In your child template add this:

```
{% extends "_layouts/_master" %}
{% block bodyClass %}css-body-class another-css-body-class{% endblock %}
```

You can also include content of parent block and append something to it:

```
{% extends "_layouts/_master" %}
{% block bodyClass %}{{parent()}} css-body-class another-css-body-class{% endblock %}
```

You can read more in twig documentation for [extends](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html).